# Check to see if you've viewed a YouTube video before?

Tags: youtube

I've got some long running series on YouTube that I enjoy watching, but I have 'viewing gaps'. Example: I started watching This Week in Startups around episode 40, and eventually went back and watched ~ 1-15 (not sure if that's the actual number) I don't always remember to catch it every week. I'm wondering if there's some part of the page I can look at when viewing a video to see that I've viewed it previously (I realize this may be imperfect since the TWI network moved authors when it became a network. but anything is better than nothing).

I'm willing to adopt a slightly different workflow if it helps solve my issue of not knowing whether I've seen an episode of something. (seriously for all the buttons YouTube has ... it won't even display on the video page that I already 'liked' that video)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are logged into YouTube, you should be view them on this page:
http://www.youtube.com/my_history

Comment: This is not an option I'd say. Imagine you're not sure if you've seen some video and you have to go thru you entire history... Is there a possibility to check if you've seen YT video on this **video's page**?

Comment: There is a "Search watch history" option in YouTube history. You can put the name of the video you want to check and hit Enter to search through all videos in that list.

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny yeah I agree. YouTube should at least display a little detail on everypage that lets you know if you already seen the video you watch. Particularly useful to know if you've already listen to a special playlist or not.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays YouTube always displays its like buttons under a video and also an indicator wether you clicked like or dislike before. So just be sure to always hit one of these buttons. When you come back you'll then know you've been there before.

[image]

Comment: I personally prefer to keep the thumb up button useful only when I really enjoyed the video I watched so I can browse the "videos you liked" YouTube section to replay very enjoyable moments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online to-do list app like [RememberTheMilk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/home/simonbrown90/) the make a note of the video id (not the URI) when you watch a video, and search for it to see whether you've watched it before. Hacky, I know.

Obviously this won't work for videos you've already watched, though. However, you might be able to recover some of that information from your browser history.